# Proof that any curve in two dimensions has a modelling differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling, continuous-geometry

I was wondering if anyone knew of a proof stating that any smooth, continuous line drawn in two dimensions must have a differential equation that models it.

Best,

James.

Comment: What requirements do you put on a differential equation? Without any constraints it would be just to say $\phi'(x)=f'(x)$ has the solution $\phi(x)=f(x)$ - if you want it to be unique you "only" have to add the condition that $\phi(a)=f(a)$ for sufficiently many $a$'s.

Comment: No requirements, the differential doesn't have to be continuous or smooth.

Essentially I need that there exists $\phi(x) = f'(x)$ for any smooth, continuous $f(x)$.

Comment: You must at least define what you mean by "smooth, continuous line" (drawn in two dimensions)...

Comment: In the sense that if you were to draw it, you would do so without lifting your pen off the page. Not necessarily that $f(x)$ has derivatives of all orders everywhere in its domain.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: For each continuous function $k$ defined on some interval I you find a unique (up to congruence) curve $c$ of class $C^2$ defined on I having $k$ as its signed curvature. In this sense, curvature determines the curve and a curve of class $C^2$ defines -- of course -- curvature.

Comment: What you said seems about right. So:

For all $k(x)$ there exists a $c(x)$ such that $c'(x) = k(x)$ on interval $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer because it is too long: I will work on $\Pi=[0,2\pi]$ out of habit but you can reparametrize if you prefer other intervals: For given $k\in C^0(\Pi)$ there exists a curve $c\in C^2(\Pi,\mathbb R^2)$ parametrized by arc length having $k$ as its signed curvature, i.e. $c''(t)\cdot Jc'(t)=k$, where $J=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0& -1\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. You can retrieve $c$ from $k$ by computing
$$
c(t):=\int_0^t\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi (s)\\ \sin\varphi(s)\end{pmatrix}\mathrm ds
$$
and $\varphi'(s)=k(s)$, $\varphi(0)=0$. Choosing different integrating constants will change the position of the curve and rotate it by a certain angle with respect to the curve I have written down. Up to this Euclidean motions, $k$ determines $c$ uniquely.
Note that the speed $|c'|$ is not enough to determine $c$ since many different curves can be for example arc length parametrized and have hence the same speed.
Curvature is in contrast really a geometric quantity as it is parameter-invariant.

You should also note that this holds only for plane curves. In higher dimensions the determination of a curve by its curvature fails rather dramatically and you need an additional datum (torsion) to get essential uniqueness.